# Keeping the fragments UI state after device has been locked / unlocked

Tags: android

Idea is that I've multiple `ImageView` components that are filled from camera in my application. For instance, I take four images and display them in four squares. I store them as `ArrayList<ImageView>`. Then, when device gets locked and then unlocked, I only see last `ImageView`, the rest of them has been destroyed / lost.

What's the best approach here? Should I use `onSaveInstanceState`? And, how would one save a list of `ImageViews` in a bundle to retrieve it later on in `onCreate`?

Comment: @Ricardo I love your solution the best. Can you please delete this comment and actually post it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: I've posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a MVVM architecture pattern and have your array of images inside your ViewModel so it can survive your UI lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

Write your imageview's image path into the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` method and later receive it inside `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method.

for example

```
@Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("path1",imagePath);
 }
```

inside onCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        // receive the parameters here
    }
}
```

> you should use the onPause() method to write any persistent data (such
>   as user edits) to storage. In addition, the method
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is called before placing the activity in
>   such a background state, allowing you to save away any dynamic
>   instance state in your activity into the given Bundle, to be later
>   received in onCreate(Bundle) if the activity needs to be re-created.
>   See the Process Lifecycle section for more information on how the
>   lifecycle of a process is tied to the activities it is hosting. Note
>   that it is important to save persistent data in onPause() instead of
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) because the latter is not part of the
>   lifecycle callbacks, so will not be called in every situation as
>   described in its documentation.

Comment: There's no path at that moment (images are not saved locally). I have them stored as objects in list. How to write that into bundle?

Comment: @PeteWonder can you show me the code how you are getting images?

Comment: I can explain you. I get an image from cameras feed. Transfer it to bitmap and put bitmap into ImageView. That ImageView is saved in list.

Comment: @PeteWonder then write those image into your local storage and save its path inside `onSaveInstanceState` method

Comment: Can I avoid writing into local storage? There's possibility to re-take the images. I'd like to save them locally later on. I mean, there should be a easier way to prevent losing images or is this the only acceptable way?

Comment: @PeteWonder what will you do with those images after displaying it inside imageviews? You need to somehow process those image like upload/edit. So it would be better to save those image locally like every app does.

Comment: That's true and I do save them locally, but the flow is like this: Take images, make sure they're correct ones (this is important. User can retake this images), do heavy processing on them and then store in local storage if process results are ok). Of course I could save them locally first and rewrite them later on, but I would not want to go that way if possible, of course. Trying to find the best option, not only just something that "works".

Comment: @PeteWonder, when the device screen is closed then Android Lifecycle calls the **onStop** method after that when the screen is turned back on again then `onCreate` method is called which resets the UI. So, you need to update UI again where user has left. So according to your situation, it would be better the save those images locally and save its path somewhere and later use them

Answer (score 0):

You can't persist raw image data in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` due to the Bundle size being limited to ~500kb, you have to have a reference to your raw image in some other form, usually by a file location or a database entry.